# How to solve zsh compinit: insecure directories issue on MacOS (other solutions failed)

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

I'm aware there are many copies of this question here, but all of their answers recommend adding

```
ZSH_DISABLE_COMPFIX="true"
```

to the top of my ~/.zshrc file. I have done this and still every time I open zsh I am greeted with

```
zsh compinit: insecure directories, run compaudit for list.
Ignore insecure directories and continue [y] or abort compinit [n]?
```

It seems that others asking this question didn't have the quotes around the true in the first sample, but I have added that. I have also run
source ~/.zshrc
Which as far as I can tell reloads the zshrc configuration. This still gives me the above warning. I'm not sure if any of these details could be relevant but I'll include them:

- This is a new zsh installation on an M1 Macbook running Big Sur
- I also have Oh My Zsh installed on top of zsh
- I earlier ran several export commands to set my nvm directory but I don't think that would be relevant

Any idea how to resolve this permissions issue? Thanks

Edit:

compaudit returns

```
/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions
/usr/local/share/zsh
```

Also, here are the other nonstandard entries in my ~/.zshrc file (in order, but there is some built-in stuff inbetween):

```
ZSH_DISABLE_COMPFIX="true"
export NVM_DIR=~/.nvm
source $(brew --prefix nvm)/nvm.sh
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/icu4c/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/icu4c/sbin:$PATH"
export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH
plugins=(git)
source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh
zstyle :compinstall filename '/Users/jonahsaltzman/.zshrc'
# End of lines configured by zsh-newuser-install
# The following lines were added by compinstall
autoload -Uz compinit
compinit
```

Comment: Did you run `compaudit`? What output does it give?

Comment: @MarlonRichert just added to the question, but compaudit gives the insecure directories as 
/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions and /usr/local/share/zsh

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55020408/zsh-compinit-insecure-directories-error-message-on-mac-after-installing-homebr) help?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

First of all, one problem here is that you’re running `compinit` *twice:* Once through Oh My Zsh (OMZ) – when you do `source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh` – and once manually. You have two options to fix this:

- If you want to keep using OMZ, then you should remove the bottom 3 lines from your `.zshrc` file.
- If you want to *stop* using OMZ, then instead, you should remove both `plugins=(git)` and `source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh` instead.

Secondly, note that `$ZSH_DISABLE_COMPFIX` is specific to OMZ and is not used by `compinit` itself. It has no effect when you call `compinit` manually. You can remove it from your `.zshrc` file.

Finally, `compinit` doesn’t show that warning for nothing. Rather than suppress it, you should instead do `chmod g-w,o-w` on the directories listed by `compaudit`. That will fix the problem and make the warning go away.

> Caveat: If you've installed `zsh` through Homebrew and you have multiple users on the same Mac, then, unfortunately, you cannot make this go away for anyone else than the user that installed Homebrew. This is a known flaw in how Homebrew manages permissions and there is currently no workaround for it. In this case, the only solution is to make the other users bypass the security checks by passing the `-u` flag to `compinit`.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you! I removed the manual compinit from my ~/.zshrc (what I gather from your answer is that OMZ runs its own compinit and thus it's unnecessary in my ~/.zshrc), and ran `chmod g-w,o-w` on the two directories returned by compaudit, now the warning is gone. A new message did appear, that oh-my-zsh.sh doesn't exist, and I removed `source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh` from ~/.zshrc as well. Now zsh starts clean as a whistle, although I'm not sure what that oh-my-zsh.sh was or why it was in there.

Comment: I started seeing this in my terminal after I ran this command `curl -s https://get.sdkman.io | bash`. Reading this answer, I check my `.zshrc` file and the last three lines were for `skin`, which I didn't want to use. After removing it, I no longer get that question in my terminal.

Answer (score 5):

You want to use:

```
compinit -u
```

To disable the annoying permissions test. It doesn't add any security on macOS. See the documentation at `zshcompsys(1)`.